# How to view contents of an embedded js file when it gives error 400

Tags: javascript, html

I subscribe to a service that lets me do custom order forms on my ecommerce site. They do this by embedding a javascript file on my page, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/file.js?ofid=27275"></script>
```

Then I can go into their site and do the cusomizations, which will appear on my order form. If I try to view the js file directly, I get an error 400. But it's obviously working properly on my site...

Is there any way to view the file contents? I'd just like to verify there's nothing shady in there...

Comment: Can you see its code in the sources tab (Chrome) or debugger tab (Firefox) in the console? (F12 to open the tools)

Comment: Duh, I always forget about that tab, thanks! That worked.